# How do I fix Run time error. Automation Error

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer

hello everyone I am facing this issue anyone please help me to fix this issue.
[image]

[image]

```
Public Sub DownloadFile()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer, currPage As HTMLDocument, url As String
Dim elements

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-insider-trading"

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.navigate url

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set currPage = objIE.document
objIE.Visible = True

'objIE.document.getElementById("CFinsidertrading-download").Click
Set elements = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("dayslisting")

For Each element In elements  'loop through all <a></a> elements...
    Set Links = element.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each link In Links
        If link.innerHTML = "3M" Then
            link.Click
            Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
            GoTo lbl3m
        End If
    Next link

Next element
lbl3m:
objIE.document.getElementById("CFinsidertrading-download").Click
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 40) 'alter to give enough time for window

Application.SendKeys "%{S}"
'Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 20) 'alter to give enough time for window
'MsgBox "File downloaded"

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the workbook in discussion has a reference to 'Microsoft Internet Controls'?

Comment: yes i am using internet explorer for it

Comment: I am not sure that you correctly understood the question... So, do you know what a reference is, no offence?

Comment: yes sir I did not understand the que about the reference

Comment: In order to work, the workbook where the above code exists must have a reference to  'Microsoft Internet Controls'. In order to add this reference, you should be in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor), where you can see the code and proceed in the next way: Click on `Tools` menu -> `References...` and firstly see in 'Available References:` left list box if the mentioned reference exists. If not, scroll down the list, find and **check it)), then press `OK`. Save the workbook and now it has such a reference...

Comment: sir i have checked that Microsoft internet control is selected in available references

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249719/discussion-between-gaurav-semwl-and-faneduru).

Comment: sir it is working fine  in another PC only problem occurs in my PC.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is fixed after downgrade the window from Window 11 to Window 10.